# String comparison after transfer through TCP socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, strcmp

I am sending a file through TCP, and have the server sending a message containing "END_OF_MESSAGE" to alert the client that they have received the whole file and can close the socket. The file is being sent, and the client receives the "END_OF_MESSAGE" string, however, when I use strcmp to compare the received information to "END_OF_MESSAGE", it never says that they match. I have tried strncmp and memcmp but am confused as to why strcmp does not tell me the strings match.

Code snippets:

Server:

```
char endMessage[MESSAGESIZE] = "END_OF_MESSAGE";

if ((send(clntSocket, endMessage, sizeof endMessage, 0))!= sizeof endMessage) DieWithError("Sending failed");
```

The above code snippet does get sent.

Client:

```
  if ((bytesRcvd = recv(sock, echoBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE - 1, 0)) <= 0)
        DieWithError("recv() failed or connection closed prematurely");
    totalBytesRcvd += bytesRcvd;   /* Keep tally of total bytes */
    echoBuffer[bytesRcvd] = '\0';  /* Terminate the string! */
    if (!(strcmp(echoBuffer, "END_OF_MESSAGE")==0)){
    printf(echoBuffer);            /* Print the echo buffer */
    printf("\n");
    }else{
      break; //break out of while loop
    }
```

the strcmp of the echoBuffer and "END_OF_MESSAGE" never returns 0, even though "END_OF_MESSAGE" is what I am sending from the server..I have tried strncmp to compare the first 3 characters ("END") to no avail.

Note: when I print out the echoBuffer, the very last one does print out END_OF_MESSAGE which is just adding to my confusion.

Does anyone have any insights into what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `MESSAGESIZE  > strlen(endMessage) ` ? (and most probably the string you received is not null-terminated, either)

Comment: You are assuming that `recv()` receives the entire `"END_OF_MESSAGE\0"` message, and ONLY the message by itself, in a single read. That is never guaranteed in TCP.  Maybe the message is received across multiple `recv()` calls.  Maybe the buffer contains some file data in the front of the buffer.  You have to account for those kinds of conditions.

Answer (score 1):

> am sending a file through TCP, and have the server sending a message containing "END_OF_MESSAGE" to alert the client that they have received the whole file and can close the socket.

Why? Just close the socket. That will tell the client exactly the same thing..

What you're attempting is fraught with difficulty. What happens if the file *contains* `END_OF_MESSAGE`? You're going to need an escape convention, and an escape for the escape, and inspect all the data when both sending and receiving.

The actual problem that you're seeing is that END_OF_MESSAGE can arrive along with the last bit of the file, so it isn't at the start of the buffer.

But it's all pointless. Just close the socket.

Comment: The problem with just closing the socket is that it does not guarantee that all of the bytes were actually received. The best option is to send the file size before sending the file data. That way, the receiver knows exactly how many bytes to read and when to stop reading. Even if you close the socket afterwards, sending the file size will let the receiver know if it actually received all of the expected bytes or not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is *exactly* what TCP *does* guarantee. You cannot receive the FIN before receiving all the data. This is a fundamental property of TCP. It is a sequenced packet exchanged, or a byte stream terminated by FIN. If any data went missing before the FIN, it will be noticed by the receiver on receipt of the FIN and caused to be retransmitted, or the connection will ultimately be reset: rather than just terminated cleanly.

Comment: As soon as the `FIN` arrives in the receiver's socket stack, it *may* report the `FIN` to the app code immediately (such as by having `recv()` return 0) even if there is previous data still pending to be read from the socket's buffer. The TCP **specification** may dictate that all pending data be processed before the FIN is reported.  But TCP **implementations** may not always follow that rule.  I have seen it happen before.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No. (a) It can't buffer the FIN after any existing data in the socket receive buffer until it has received all the prior sequence numbers. (b) It has to deliver all the data in the socket receive buffer before the FIN. If you've seen otherwise you've seen a catastrophic bug.

Comment: That may be how it *should* be, but **I have run code on production systems** where `recv()` returned 0 after `FIN` was sent even though not all data had been read yet (I haven't seen it happen recently, though). If it is a bug, it is a bug in the OS itself. Doesn't always happens, but it **can** happen. I'm just saying, it is not wise to rely on `FIN` alone to signal end-of-data if data integrity is important (it usually is).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Very hard to believe. Never seen that in 30 years. It is a basic violation of TCP segment sequencing.